# How shared_ptr detects if it has to call delete[] or delete

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I am curious to know, how shared_ptr class decides whether it has to call `delete` or `delete[]` for the below statements?

a. `boost::shared_ptr <char> ptr(new char);`

b. `boost::shared_ptr <char []> ptr(new char[100]);`

Comment: I would imagine you tell it which to call with the parameter, it being either `<char>` or `<char[]>`.

Comment: Boost have many types of "smart" pointers, but none called `boost::smart_ptr`.

Comment: As for your question, please do some research about [*specialization*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/template-specialization-c/).

Comment: The `<T>` version is specialized to always use `delete` by default. The `<T[]>` version is specialized to always use `delete[]` by default. There is no decision to make. The template parameter determines which specialization is used.

Answer (score 3):

It is done via template specialization. Here is the simple demonstration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    foo( T* d ) : m_data{ d } {  }
    ~foo() {
        if ( m_data )
        std::cout << "delete called." << std::endl;
    }

private:
    T* m_data {};
};

template<typename T>
struct foo<T[]>
{
    foo( T* d ) : m_data { d } { }
    ~foo() {
        if ( m_data )
            delete[] m_data;
        std::cout << "delete[] called." << std::endl;
    }
private:
    T* m_data {};
};

int main()
{
    foo<char> inst_1 { new char };
    foo<char []> inst_2 { new char[ 100 ] { 'a' } };
}
```

[online example](http://cpp.sh/2i5zl)

For `T[]` types, `struct foo<T[]>` instantiated, so compile-time polymorphism is done via template specialization and `smart_ptr` handles deallocation of both array and normal types with the help of this feature.